# Cake PHP 3 makes untimely logout

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I made a chat system on my cakePHP 3 application but it disturbs other component of my application. All authenticated user have untimely logout when they are navigating on the website.

The front of the chat use angularjs and the BDD updated by cakePHP.
The administrator of the chat get all messages every 10s and it's also update the field modified of the chatApplication. I update the modified field manually :

```
    $chat_application->modified = \Cake\I18n\Time::now();
    $this->ChatConversations->ChatApplications->save($chat_application);
```

I use this field to know if an administrator is online or not.

All other user get their list of message every 10s but it doesn't change something in the DB (Mysql).

Request made by the admin :

```
     $http.post('/getConversations.json',{name:'villa-bali-booking.com',password:'*******',user:'Administrator'}).success(function(data){ ... });
```

Request made by users :

```
    $.post("/getMessages.json",{uuid : uuid, name : 'Visitor'}, function (data){ .... });
```

What can cause those logout ? Users who are disconnected are not using the chat.

Thank you :)

#### Edit  : app.php of cakephp if the problem is inside

```
<?php
return [
/**
 * Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 * true: Errors and warnings shown.
 */
'debug' => false,

/**
 * Configure basic information about the application.
 *
 * - namespace - The namespace to find app classes under.
 * - encoding - The encoding used for HTML + database connections.
 * - base - The base directory the app resides in. If false this
 *   will be auto detected.
 * - dir - Name of app directory.
 * - webroot - The webroot directory.
 * - wwwRoot - The file path to webroot.
 * - baseUrl - To configure CakePHP to *not* use mod_rewrite and to
 *   use CakePHP pretty URLs, remove these .htaccess
 *   files:
 *      /.htaccess
 *      /webroot/.htaccess
 *   And uncomment the baseUrl key below.
 * - fullBaseUrl - A base URL to use for absolute links.
 * - imageBaseUrl - Web path to the public images directory under webroot.
 * - cssBaseUrl - Web path to the public css directory under webroot.
 * - jsBaseUrl - Web path to the public js directory under webroot.
 * - paths - Configure paths for non class based resources. Supports the
 *   `plugins`, `templates`, `locales` subkeys, which allow the definition of
 *   paths for plugins, view templates and locale files respectively.
 */
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'base' => false,
    'dir' => 'src',
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,
    // 'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
    'fullBaseUrl' => false,
    'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
    'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
    'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
    'paths' => [
        'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
        'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
        'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
    ],
],

/**
 * Security and encryption configuration
 *
 * - salt - A random string used in security hashing methods.
 *   The salt value is also used as the encryption key.
 *   You should treat it as extremely sensitive data.
 */
'Security' => [
    'salt' => '**********',
    'level' => 'medium'
],

/**
 * Apply timestamps with the last modified time to static assets (js, css, images).
 * Will append a querystring parameter containing the time the file was modified.
 * This is useful for busting browser caches.
 *
 * Set to true to apply timestamps when debug is true. Set to 'force' to always
 * enable timestamping regardless of debug value.
 */
'Asset' => [
    // 'timestamp' => true,
],

/**
 * Configure the cache adapters.
 */
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'path' => CACHE,
    ],

    /**
     * Configure the cache used for general framework caching. Path information,
     * object listings, and translation cache files are stored with this
     * configuration.
     */
    '_cake_core_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_core_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+2 minutes',
    ],

    /**
     * Configure the cache for model and datasource caches. This cache
     * configuration is used to store schema descriptions, and table listings
     * in connections.
     */
    '_cake_model_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_model_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+2 minutes',
    ],
],

/**
 * Configure the Error and Exception handlers used by your application.
 *
 * By default errors are displayed using Debugger, when debug is true and logged
 * by Cake\Log\Log when debug is false.
 *
 * In CLI environments exceptions will be printed to stderr with a backtrace.
 * In web environments an HTML page will be displayed for the exception.
 * With debug true, framework errors like Missing Controller will be displayed.
 * When debug is false, framework errors will be coerced into generic HTTP errors.
 *
 * Options:
 *
 * - `errorLevel` - int - The level of errors you are interested in capturing.
 * - `trace` - boolean - Whether or not backtraces should be included in
 *   logged errors/exceptions.
 * - `log` - boolean - Whether or not you want exceptions logged.
 * - `exceptionRenderer` - string - The class responsible for rendering
 *   uncaught exceptions.  If you choose a custom class you should place
 *   the file for that class in src/Error. This class needs to implement a
 *   render method.
 * - `skipLog` - array - List of exceptions to skip for logging. Exceptions that
 *   extend one of the listed exceptions will also be skipped for logging.
 *   E.g.:
 *   `'skipLog' => ['Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException', 'Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException']`
 */
'Error' => [
    'errorLevel' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'exceptionRenderer' => 'Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer',
    'skipLog' => [],
    'log' => true,
    'trace' => true,
],

/**
 * Email configuration.
 *
 * You can configure email transports and email delivery profiles here.
 *
 * By defining transports separately from delivery profiles you can easily
 * re-use transport configuration across multiple profiles.
 *
 * You can specify multiple configurations for production, development and
 * testing.
 *
 * ### Configuring transports
 *
 * Each transport needs a `className`. Valid options are as follows:
 *
 *  Mail   - Send using PHP mail function
 *  Smtp   - Send using SMTP
 *  Debug  - Do not send the email, just return the result
 *
 * You can add custom transports (or override existing transports) by adding the
 * appropriate file to src/Network/Email.  Transports should be named
 * 'YourTransport.php', where 'Your' is the name of the transport.
 *
 * ### Configuring delivery profiles
 *
 * Delivery profiles allow you to predefine various properties about email
 * messages from your application and give the settings a name. This saves
 * duplication across your application and makes maintenance and development
 * easier. Each profile accepts a number of keys. See `Cake\Network\Email\Email`
 * for more information.
 */
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail',
    ],
    'smtp' => [
                    'className' => 'Smtp',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => '**********',
        'password' => '********',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true,
    ]
],

'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => '******',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
],

/**
 * Connection information used by the ORM to connect
 * to your application's datastores.
 * Drivers include Mysql Postgres Sqlite Sqlserver
 * See vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Driver for complete list
 */
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,

        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',         
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '*****',
        'password' => '*****',
        'database' => '*******',



        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,

        /**
         * Set identifier quoting to true if you are using reserved words or
         * special characters in your table or column names. Enabling this
         * setting will result in queries built using the Query Builder having
         * identifiers quoted when creating SQL. It should be noted that this
         * decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and
         * manipulated before being executed.
         */
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

        /**
         * During development, if using MySQL < 5.6, uncommenting the
         * following line could boost the speed at which schema metadata is
         * fetched from the database. It can also be set directly with the
         * mysql configuration directive 'innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'
         * which is the recommended value in production environments
         */
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],

    /**
     * The test connection is used during the test suite.
     */
    'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'my_app',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'database' => 'test_myapp',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
],

/**
 * Configures logging options
 */
'Log' => [
    'debug' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => 'debug',
        'levels' => ['notice', 'info', 'debug'],
    ],
    'error' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => 'error',
        'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
    ],
],

/**
 *
 * Session configuration.
 *
 * Contains an array of settings to use for session configuration. The
 * `defaults` key is used to define a default preset to use for sessions, any
 * settings declared here will override the settings of the default config.
 *
 * ## Options
 *
 * - `cookie` - The name of the cookie to use. Defaults to 'CAKEPHP'.
 * - `cookiePath` - The url path for which session cookie is set. Maps to the
 *   `session.cookie_path` php.ini config. Defaults to base path of app.
 * - `timeout` - The time in minutes the session should be valid for.
 *    Pass 0 to disable checking timeout.
 * - `defaults` - The default configuration set to use as a basis for your session.
 *    There are four built-in options: php, cake, cache, database.
 * - `handler` - Can be used to enable a custom session handler. Expects an
 *    array with at least the `engine` key, being the name of the Session engine
 *    class to use for managing the session. CakePHP bundles the `CacheSession`
 *    and `DatabaseSession` engines.
 * - `ini` - An associative array of additional ini values to set.
 *
 * The built-in `defaults` options are:
 *
 * - 'php' - Uses settings defined in your php.ini.
 * - 'cake' - Saves session files in CakePHP's /tmp directory.
 * - 'database' - Uses CakePHP's database sessions.
 * - 'cache' - Use the Cache class to save sessions.
 *
 * To define a custom session handler, save it at src/Network/Session/<name>.php.
 * Make sure the class implements PHP's `SessionHandlerInterface` and set
 * Session.handler to <name>
 *
 * To use database sessions, load the SQL file located at config/Schema/sessions.sql
 */
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout'  => 60
],
];
```

### Edit :

Hello, I have news, even if I deactivate the chat, the problem occurs but less often. I found an error in the apache log, but I don't really understand :s

```
    [Sat Jul 04 04:25:27 2015] [error] [client **.**.**.**] [host www.********.com] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/homez.***/***/www/webroot/index.php" aborted: read failed, referer: http://www.********.com/periods/112
    [Sat Jul 04 04:25:27 2015] [error] [client **.**.**.**] [host www.********.com] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/homez.***/***/www/webroot/index.php", referer: http://www.********.com/periods/112
    [Sat Jul 04 04:25:27 2015] [error] [client **.**.**.**] [host www.********.com] FastCGI: An error happend on Fastcgi processing, fallback to CGI, referer: http://www.********.com/periods/112
```

## EDIT:

The problem seems to be resolved, I posted a ticket to my hosting OVH, they said that it's not their fault but the problem doesn't appear anymore. So I guess they did a modification.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: One cause for the session being invalidated are 404s hitting the app - that's the first thing to check for. `Users who are disconnected are not using the chat.` - then the chat isn't likely to be a factor the actions of one user aren't going to affect the validity of _other_ user's session unless something pretty weird is setup/going on.

Comment: There isn't any 404s :-( , when no body use the chat, there isn't the problem... I added my app.php file on my first post if there is a mistake inside. Thank you for helping ;) Maybe all sessions are deleted because of a bug ? Maybe a cache problem ?

Comment: You are probably logging in users using the javascript requests, this will cause the sessions id to be regenerated. If you do it fast enough a couple times, the session id will get out of sync with the browser cookie. That causes an immediate logout

Comment: The javascript request doesn't use session, user and password are checked every time. I looked at the network utility of Chrome, the cookie doesn't change in the request. It's really weird :/ Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved, I posted a ticket to my hosting OVH, they said that it's not their fault but the problem doesn't appear anymore. So I guess they did a modification.